# How to set layout for calendar for all decive ios

Tags: ios

I am facing problem  with calendar. when I am running it on device  iPhone 5s then its works: To click the link check  screen short of iPhone 5s

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyhGm.png]

Otherwise when i am running the same app on iPhone 6 the its layout has change. To click the link check  screen short of iPhone 6

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl1Ak.png]

this is my code:

```
calendar = [[DSLCalendarView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

Please Help me solve this problem

Comment: can you try log of calendar frame ? DSLCalendarView class may be not supported code in different device hight and width

Comment: I have no idea of the log calendar frame can you send me the code of the log of the calendar frame